# Calling delegate methods and calling selectors

Tags: iphone

I'm new to the concept of delegates and selectors when used with notifications.  So my first question is,

1) Let's say you have a button that has a delegate that implements some `doWork` method.  If you want the same functionality that's in the method, is it 'ok' to just call that method?  I didn't know if that was considered good coding practices and/or if you should do that, or do something different in getting that type of functionality.  Like if that is ok architecture?

2) Similarly, with NSNotificationCenter, I see some code that posts a notification.  Then there's a `HandleSegmentedControl:(NSNotification *)notification` method.  If I want to manually have that functionality, but without pressing the segment control, is it 'ok' to just take that functionality out of that method and put it in a new method so it would look like this:

Original:

```
- (void)HandleSegmentedControl:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary *dict = [userInfo notification];
    // do stuff with the dictionary
}
```

New:

```
- (void)HandleSegmentedControl:(NSNotification *)notification {
     NSDictionary *dict = [userInfo notification];
     [self newMethod:dict];
}

- (void)newMethod:(NSDictionary *)dict {
    // do stuff with the dictionary
}

- (void)myOtherMethodThatNeedsTheSameFunctionality {
     NSDictionary *dict = // create some dictionary
     [self newMethod:dict];
}
```

Sorry if these are basic questions.  I'm not sure what the best practices are for things like this and wanted to start the right way.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If the delegate protocol implements the `doWork` method as a required method, then yes. However, if it is an optional method, or if you want to be extra safe, you should use

   ```
   if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(doWork)]) {
       [delegate doWork];
   }
   ```
2. Sure, that seems like a reasonable thing to do. It is a common way to make your code more robust. The notification's userInfo is there so you can send data as you like. However, I think in your code you meant `[notification userInfo]` not `[userInfo notification]`.